# How to optimize my code to run each fetch in parallel

Tags: c#

I am trying to refactor my code below to increase its speed performance. I have noticed that the code in the foreach seems to be executed one after another, instead of in parallel to speed up the execution of the `UpdateSites` function. I just need `UpdateSites` to run in the background. What can I do to increase its performance?

```
await UpdateSites(currentUserSites);
private async Task<List<Site>> UpdateSites(List<Site> sites)
{
    foreach (var site in sites)
    {
        var newSite = await FetchSite(site.SiteId);
        site.address = newSite.address;
        site.phone = newSite.phone;
    }
    return sites;
}
public async Task<SiteSimple> FetchSite(int siteId)
{
    var url = $"/site/{siteId}/simple";
    return await ExecuteRestRequest<SiteSimple>(url, Method.GET);
}
```

Comment: This? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop

Comment: @mjwills I have added `FetchSite`. `ExecuteRestRequest` is a very long function that I didn't include.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I utilize multiple HttpClients for bulk async GET requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54072800/should-i-utilize-multiple-httpclients-for-bulk-async-get-requests)

Comment: Straight to *TPL DataFlow*, do not *Pass-Go*

Answer (score 2):

I refactored your code according to your need.

```
private Task<List<Site>> UpdateSites(List<Site> sites)
{
    return sites.Select(x => FetchSite(site.SiteId))
}


public Task<SiteSimple> FetchSite(int siteId)
{
    var url = $"/site/{siteId}/simple";
    return ExecuteRestRequest<SiteSimple>(url, Method.GET);
}
```

then

```
var resultList = await Task.WhenAll(UpdateSites(currentUserSites));
foreach (var item in result)
{
    //make your operation
}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit?view=netframework-4.7.2 may be of interest.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use `Task.WaitAll` to fetch all tasks in parallel

```
private async Task<List<Site>> UpdateSites(List<Site> sites)
{
    var newSites = (await Task.WhenAll(sites.Select(site => FetchSite(site.SiteId))
                   .ToList();

    for(int i = 0; i < sites.Count; ++i)
    {
        sites[i].address = newSites[i].address;
        sites[i].phone= newSites[i].phone;
    }
    return sites;
}
```

Comment: the code inside for loop looks redundant as well, since the newSites already has same values :), that is why I did not include it in my answer. If you also delete that part, our answers will be same :D

Comment: @Simonare FetchSite works as i expect it you are right. `newSites` and `sites` will contain the same (different instance, same value) sites. But i don't know where the sites are used otherwhere and updating them is maybe required.